# Small graphics card with low power requirements, that supports 2 x 4k monitors

Tags: graphics-cards

I have a small case for this machine and am trying to add a small (low profile?) GPU to it, to support 2x 4k monitors.  I say small because there's not much space left, and I'm keen to keep the temperatures down - so passive cooling is ideal. I'm also a little nervous about quite how much power is left from the 750W PSU.

This is NOT a gaming rig - it's just for desktop use for development - so the only real requirement is that it can support 2x 4k monitors with very low framerates.

Appreciate any ideas!

Comment: 1050 ti? That support 4k video playback AFAIK

Comment: What is the CPU in the system? How many other power-consuming components are in there? 750W is usually a lot of headroom. -- Also "Low Profile" means something very specific. It is the name for those half-height expansion slots. Does your case have that size of expansion slot or is it the standard full height? You probably meant to ask for a card that takes up a single slot. Many cards use 2 or more.

Comment: CPU is a threadripper.  The box is running pretty hot :)  Indeed yes - definitely only want to use one PCI slot.